# Adding icons to specific coordinates in chart.js

Tags: angularjs, charts, icons, chart.js, imageicon

---

### CHART JS

i am using chart js to plot the chart  my requirement is to plot the icons on the chart on date basis of  the y axis.
i can able to plot the chart , but i want to plot multiple icons on that chart instead of one icon.
Below is the working code in html and the chart image link** i've tried the stack overflow links  it's not working `can anybody help me out on this`
Edited with new codes which is working

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Line Chart Test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function () {
  var size = 20;
  
  
    Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    draw: function() {
      Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

      var scale = this.scale;
      [
       { x: 1, y: 50 }, 
  { x: 1, y: 45 }, 
  { x: 1, y: 40 }, 
  { x: 1, y: 35 }, 
  { x: 1, y: 30 }, 
  { x: 1, y: 25 }, 
  { x: 1, y: 20 }, 
  { x: 1, y: 15 }, 
  { x: 1, y: 10 }, 
  { x: 2, y: 40 },
  { x: 2, y: 40 },
  { x: 3, y: 30 },
        { x: 4, y: 10 },
  { x: 4, y: 15 }
      ].forEach(function(p) {
        ctx.drawImage(img, scale.calculateX(p.x) - size / 2, scale.calculateY(p.y) - size / 2, size, size);
      })
    }
  });
  
    var data = {
        labels: ["Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [25, 45, 35, 14, 81, 22, 85]
            },{
                label: "Prime and Fibonacci",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
            }
        ]
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
    var options = { };
    var lineChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data,  options);
  }
  
  img.src = 'D:/WorkSpace/angchart/WebContent/images/MD.png';
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <canvas id="lineChart" height="450" width="800"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

so could any body can help me out of this on how to add a mutiple images in that chart or code

Comment: Your question is unclear and you have provided far too much code. Please review both of these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i did changed the code which is working and the chart image, please check it out now